# Use "dict of dicts" or "list of dicts" for storing data from CSV in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

**What is the better option in Python?**

1. A `dict` with 10000 keys, each containing a `list` with 10 items
2. A `dict` with 10000 keys, each containing a  `dict` with 10 "sub-keys"
3. A `dict` with the 10 "sub-keys", each containing a `dict` with the 10000 keys
4. Using pandas library (as suggested by @RomanPerekhrest in the comments)

Option 2 seems a bit more programmer-friendly than option 1 (working with e.g. `mydict['long-ID1']['street']` rather than `mydict['long-ID1'][3]`).

However, I am afraid that this might cause much unneeded overhead. I don't expect the number or order of sub-keys (like `'street'`) to change in the future).

I am looking for the **"best" option** in terms of **performance** (speed of lookup), while also considering **storage space** (in RAM and when saving with pickle).

**Background**

I am parsing a ~ 4MB CSV file with ~10000 lines (stations) with these columns:

**ID** - unique ~30 character string
**name, street, city, ...** - strings
**lat,long** - GPS coordinates
**date** - take a guess
**jsonstring** - some nested dicts

I want to import the data into python as a dict `station` using **ID** as the key to allow fast lookups `station['some-id']`. I will then perform several million lookups in the dict, usually only looking at 1-2 of the 10 columns for each station, depending on use case.

The latter is why, while writing this question, I thought of option 3... the downside I see is that the 10000 keys are much longer than the 10 keys, so repeating that large dict 10 times is probably not such a good idea in terms of memory?

** Update **
Based on [@Giova's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57563695/669202), I put together this performance comparison of options 1 and 2, which you also find on [repl.it here](https://repl.it/repls/SolidHotpinkComma):

```
from timeit import timeit

def listops(n:int, l):
    for i in range(n):
        t = l[i]
    return l

def dictops(n:int, d):
    for i in range(n):
        t = d["nice_key_%1d"%i]
    return d


n= 10
l = []
for i in range(n):
    l.append(i)
d = dict()
for i in range(n):
    d["nice_key_%1d"%i] = None
t1=timeit(lambda: listops(n, l), number=1000000)
t2=timeit(lambda: dictops(n, d), number=1000000)
print("list:",t1)
print("dict:",t2)
```

Note this times only the speed of lookup, in contrast to Giova's code snippet which also looks at creation of the data structure, which I am not interested in.

Results:

```
list: 4.312716690998059
dict: 14.279126501001883
```

I guess the simplest for answering the "storage space" part of my question is actually implementing both and checking for size of the pickle files?

Comment: Option 4 - `pandas` ! )

Comment: Speed and memory space are always at odds. My suggestion would be to go for a full dictionary-based solution, memory is cheap nowadays. This solution has the added benefit of being very clear what is contained where. If you want to be somewhat fancier, use `dataclasses` and dump all that data in an object with slotted attributes. Lastly, benchmark memory and performance, and then make a decision of which part is more important for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest - first glance looked interesting, will put the pandas docs on my reading list :-).

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg, actually, the option 1 would be the most lightweight in terms of resources, but it requires a strict convention - which position/index represents which column name

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel - your `dataclasses` idea sounds nice and easy tom implement. This would be a more fancy version of my option 2, right, where I essentially only need to define the data type?

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg probably the dataclass idea is a bad one for your situation. `pandas`, would be eventually bad idea too since you'll need a plethora of other packages just for loading and storing the csv in memory. But if you're looking in doing analytics on it then go for `pandas`. If it's a more general programming situation, just go for your solution 2, and if you find yourself with memory issues, then you solve that.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Why is dataclass bad? Looked promising to me at first sight, essentially like a dict with fixed keys and data types per key, which matches my dataset?

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg, in the end, it'll all depend on what do you want to do with the data you're loading. Using `dataclasses` might be a bad idea because it could incur in more overhead as using a dictionary, and is not solving all your problems.

Answer (score 2):

Between the option you mentioned, the ones using dictionaries (2, 3) are better in terms access speed. Which one is better between 2 and 3 really depends on how you prefere to retrieve elements.

Consider also you can associate to each row a progressive number as key to the first dictionary, by operating that way, reasonably supposing string consumes much memory than small numbers, that trick would waste less memory.

Option 1 should only be considered if speed is not that much important; cause of the significant amount of time spent by list methods. That can be even easily empirically verified with a simple snippet:

```py
from elapsed import TimeIt


def listops(n:int):
    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        l.append(i)
    for i in range(n):
        t = i in l
    return l


def dictops(n:int):
    d = dict()
    for i in range(n):
        d[i] = None
    for i in range(n):
        t = i in d
    return d

TimeIt(lambda: listops(10), 1000000, logger_name=__name__, msg='listops(10)')
TimeIt(lambda: dictops(10), 1000000, logger_name=__name__, msg='dictops(10)')
```

Here we have two functions, `listops` and 'dictops', creating respectively a `list` and a `dict` of given `n` integers and then checking for the presence of each inserted integer. The code wants basically checking only construction, insertion, and presence testing for `list` and `dict`. This logs out the following timings:

```sh
Elapsed time '1000000 times listops(10)':  3.559521 seconds.
Elapsed time '1000000 times dictops(10)':  2.720709 seconds.
```

[Note that `TimeIt` (camel case) is a custom class I did for my purposes, but you can easily use `timeit` from the `timeit` module.]

Even if is not explicitly part of your question, I would advice using `sqlite` in-memory database, with indexes on columns used in search query and prepared statement ready to be fired on demand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be clear, my options 2 and 3 would use the same keys, it would just be different in how they are nested: `stations['long-string-ID']['street']` vs `stations['street']['long-string-ID']`.

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg my bad, sorry. I edited the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Reading your answer again, I am surprised by your statement about speed of option 1. You are saying doing an explicit lookup on `stations['long-string-ID'][3]` (dict containing list, where I access list element 3 which by my convention would be street) would be slower than `stations['long-string-ID']['street']`? Note I am not considering `list` for the 10000 keys in any of the scenarios: each list of 10 elements would get created in one go, and assigned as the value of one of the 10000 `dict` elements.

Comment: Considering you didn't post any code, even if would be easy to figuring out what you would have wanted to write down, depending on how you use lists, you may use methods whose time complexity is O(n) or O(k), that would be more difficult using dictionaries whose only operations of order O(n) are the copy and deletion. Does that make sense?